# MYSQL Trigger UPDATE field when data is entered

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MYSQL table named **procurement** with the following columns...

```
| id | province | sample_result | image | status   |
| 1  | prov_1   | 3             | url   | Complete |
| 2  | prov_2   | 12            | NULL  |          |
| 3  | prov_3   | 45            | NULL  |          |
| 4  | prov_4   |               | url   |          |
```

I would like to create a TRIGGER that updates the column "status" with "Complete" when **both** the sample_result and image columns are updated and no longer NULL. If either one is NULL then no update is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can set NEW. values in a before trigger and since mysql copies OLD. values to NEW. values before it acquires NEW. values from the update then testing NEW. values is safe

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
( id int, province varchar(10), sample_result int, image varchar(10), status varchar(10));
insert into t values
( 1  , 'prov_1'   , 3             , 'url'    , 'Complete'),
( 2  , 'prov_2'   , 12            , NULL     ,  null     ),
( 3  , 'prov_3'   , 45            , NULL     ,  null     ),
( 4  , 'prov_4'   , null          , 'url'    ,  null     );

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before update on t
for each row
begin
    if new.sample_result is not null and new.image is not null then
        set new.status = 'Complete';
    end if ;
end $$
delimiter ;

update t set sample_result = 2 where id = 2;
update t set sample_result = 1 where id = 4;
update t set image = 'url' where id = 3;

select * from t;

+------+----------+---------------+-------+----------+
| id   | province | sample_result | image | status   |
+------+----------+---------------+-------+----------+
|    1 | prov_1   |             3 | url   | Complete |
|    2 | prov_2   |             2 | NULL  | NULL     |
|    3 | prov_3   |            45 | url   | Complete |
|    4 | prov_4   |             1 | url   | Complete |
+------+----------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: This works on all versions of MySQL? I thought you can not use triggers on same table trigger action is made on.

Comment: @ikiK'In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html You cannot otherwise action(insert/update/delete) the table which fired the trigger. As to all versions of mysql dunno -  but certainly back to 5.6 if anyone is on earlier then good luck to them.